# Find biggest ArrayList from a multi dimensional ArrayList by count in Android

Tags: android, arrays, list, arraylist

I has a `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. It can have more than one array in itself. Sometimes maybe 5 or 6. Now I want to get the largest `ArrayList` from my multi dimensional `ArrayList` by using it's size. I don't know how to achieve this. Hence i'm posting here. Thanks in advance.

For example:

[[a, b, c], [d, e, f, g, h, i, j]]

By using the following code I'm creating the `ArrayList` of ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < devArray.size(); i++) {
        String devName = devArray.get(i);
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str: strArray) {
            array.add(str);
        }
        arrays.add(array);
    }
```

Comment: Where's your code ?

Answer (score 3):

See if it works.

```
int maxListTracker = 0, maxListPosition = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++ ) {
        ArrayList al = arrays.get(i)
        if(al.size() > maxListTracker) {
           maxListTracker = al.size();
           maxListPosition = i;
        }
}

ArrayList biggestList = arrays.get(maxListPosition);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
        int biggestArrayCount = 0;
        int biggestArrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < devArray.size(); i++) {
            String devName = devArray.get(i);
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String str: strArray) {
                array.add(str);
            }
            if(array.size() > biggestArrayCount) {
                biggestArrayCount = array.size();
                biggestArrayIndex = i;
            }
            arrays.add(array);
        }
```

Since this is the simplest solution, you even can save only index and later can get size by `arrays.get(index).size;` and you either can save both of them in a HashMap;

Comment: I think this only gets the count of biggest arraylist. I want the biggest whole arraylist

Comment: you may follow the edited answer @PraveenKumar, you may accept if it works :)